# RxJava 1.x .zip() not working on RxJava 2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

i'm trying to learn chain requests with RxJava + Retrofit + Kotlin.
The tutorial i was follwing was using RxJava 1.x, so when i try to re-implement with RxJava 2.x the i cannot get **.zip()** to work.

It's a simple app using Star Wars API, returning a list of movies, ando for each movie, get the characters from them.

```
fun loadMoviesFull(): Observable<Movie> {
    return service.listMovies()
            .flatMap { filmResults -> Observable.from(filmResults.results) }
            .flatMap { film ->
                Observable.zip(
                        Observable.just(Movie(film.title, film.episodeId, ArrayList<Character>())),
                        Observable.from(film.personUrls)
                                .flatMap { personUrl ->
                                    service.loadPerson(Uri.parse(personUrl).lastPathSegment)
                                }
                                .map { person ->
                                    Character(person!!.name, person.gender)
                                }
                                .toList(),
                        { movie, characters ->
                            movie.characters.addAll(characters)
                            movie
                        })
            }
}
```

If you want to see the whole implementation of the tutorial, this is the link(The comments are in portuguese):
http://www.nglauber.com.br/2017/03/rxjava-kotlin-retrofit-star-wars-api.html

I just want to know the syntax for ir, because i cannot implement on 2.x.

Thank you so much and i'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error compiler produces but very probably your function should return `Observable<List<Movie>>`, `zip`'s `BiFunction` requires passing types explicitly and should not have single `movie` at the end. And of course `.toList()` at the end.

Full code:

```
fun loadMoviesFull(): Observable<List<Movie>> {
    return service.listMovies()
            .flatMap { filmResults -> Observable.from(filmResults.results) }
            .flatMap { film ->
                Observable.zip(
                        Observable.just(Movie(film.title, film.episodeId, ArrayList<Character>())),
                        Observable.from(film.personUrls)
                                .flatMap { personUrl ->
                                    service.loadPerson(Uri.parse(personUrl).lastPathSegment)
                                }
                                .map { person ->
                                    Character(person!!.name, person.gender)
                                }
                                .toList(),
                        BiFunction<Movie, Character, Movie>{ movie, characters ->
                            movie.characters.addAll(characters)
                        })
            }.toList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me add a comment due to insufficient reputation, hence posting as an answer. Are you using [rxkotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)? There are a number of helper functions, including `Observable.zip()` that help with the SAM ambiguity issues when using Rx2. Without knowing what your error is, that's the best advice I can give.